# Im getting an error in the first member (2nd line of code)

Tags: functional-programming, f#

getting an error message on the first 'member' part,

```
type Account = {accountNumber:string; mutable balance:float} 

    member this.Withdraw(cash:float) = 
        if cash > this.balance then
            Console.WriteLine("Insufficient Funds. The Amount you wish to withdraw is greater than your current account balance.")
        else
            this.balance <- this.balance - cash
            Console.WriteLine("You have withdrawn £" + cash.ToString() + ". Your balance is now: £" + this.balance.ToString())

    member this.Deposit(cash:float) =
        this.balance <- this.balance + cash
        Console.WriteLine("£" + cash.ToString() + " Cash Deposited. Your new Balance is: £" + this.balance.ToString())

    member this.Print = 
        Console.WriteLine("Account Number: " + this.accountNumber)
        Console.WriteLine("Balance: £" + this.balance.ToString())
```

the program should, define an f# type named Account that contains an accountNumber (string), and balance (float) field. the type should include methods to withdraw and deposit money into the account along with a print member that displays the field values on a single line within the console. If the withdrawal amount is greater than the account balance then the transaction should be cancelled and a suitable message displayed.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, the only thing that is wrong with your code is the indentation - when you are adding members to a record, the `member` keyword should be aligned with the `{` of the record definition.

You can define the type correctly by adding a new line after `=` on the first line:

```
type Account = 
    {accountNumber:string; mutable balance:float} 

    member this.Withdraw(cash:float) = 
        if cash > this.balance then
            Console.WriteLine("Insufficient Funds. The Amount you wish to withdraw is greater than your current account balance.")
        else
            this.balance <- this.balance - cash
            Console.WriteLine("You have withdrawn £" + cash.ToString() + ". Your balance is now: £" + this.balance.ToString())

    member this.Deposit(cash:float) =
        this.balance <- this.balance + cash
        Console.WriteLine("£" + cash.ToString() + " Cash Deposited. Your new Balance is: £" + this.balance.ToString())

    member this.Print() = 
        Console.WriteLine("Account Number: " + this.accountNumber)
        Console.WriteLine("Balance: £" + this.balance.ToString())
```

Another issue in your code is that `Print` is defined as a property rather than a method, so my version also adds the `()` parameter - this is not exactly a bug, but it is definitely a good practice to define side-effectful operations as methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my program is giving me warning (Main module of program is empty: nothing will happen when it is run), does this have to do with the fact that I need to put the deposit member before the withdraw member (as there would not be anything in the program to use)

Comment: @BenjaminDanielMorgan that’s a different problem. The Account class is good now. Please ask a new question.